# first record in a subset of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like:

[image]

I want to select all columns in the dataframe but only the top 1 record (based on amount). So in this case, I would expect to see:

```
1 Long  10
2 Short -2
```

Any ideas how to do this in Pandas ?

Comment: You only want to see the top 1 row when provided with a value for column Position, e.g. Long?

Comment: the Position column is irrelevant......I just want all possible ID's with the amount that is the largest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can also use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by **ID**( it keep **first** by default):

```
df.sort_values("Amount", ascending=False).drop_duplicates('ID')
```

Another alternative is [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) with **`as_index = False`** to keep index like a **column**

```
df.sort_values("Amount", ascending=False).groupby("ID",as_index = False).first()
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort the dataframe by the amount in the decreasing order (just in case they are not sorted yet), then group by the id (or position, whatever is relevant), and pick the first line from each group:

```
df.sort_values("Amount", ascending=False).groupby("ID").first()
```